# Django IntegrityError When Updating an Object

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-orm

I'm upgrading our project from python 2 to 3 and observing inconsistent behaviors regarding creating/saving objects with null values.

Consider a `CharField` defined with `default=''` (and **without** `null=True`)

On the python 2 branch, creating an object with that field set to None causes exception but once created, setting the field to None, then saving, works fine (though `None` is converted to `''`, probably by Django)

On the python 3 branch, creating *and* updating with `field=None` for the same model causes exception (`IntegrityError`).

I'm not sure what the expected behavior is, if a field doesn't define `null=True`, it makes sense to error out when updating that field with None. However, saving with None clearly has worked on the python 2 branch for a while now (several years)..unless that was a bug and not a feature?

Anyone have run into the same issue before?

*note*: Both branches have the same Django (1.9 for now, updating to 2 after python 3 conversion), same version of MySQL (5.7.22), python 2 branch runs on Ubuntu 14.04, and python 3 on 16.04.

**Update**:

I've decided to clean up code that sets any field without `null=True` to `None`.

I mean, defining a field that's non-nullable then setting it to null, who does that?? :D

On a more serious note, can someone confirm if the Django ORM at any point was being smart and converted `None` values to empty strings? Some of the code I'm dealing with is quite old, maybe it did what's expected at the time of writing. Still, can't confirm.. but as my case shows, this behavior may not be reliable, so I'm doing the more sensible thing.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/

The current solution sounds hackish. You're requiring a blank default and then overriding the default with None... which is storing null in the database. That's a complicated way of just implementing null=True.

You're already storing null in the database and you're already refactoring the code. That sounds like a good opportunity to rewrite these models correctly.

Comment: thanks, @ShaunOverton, what you suggest makes sense, and I totally agree. However I'm a bit confused as to what the expected behavior is here, when you set None to a field with `null=False`, should it silently convert it to the default value (like on my python2 branch) or throw an IntegrityError (like on my python3 branch)? Actually I'm not even sure it's caused by python version, but not sure where to look either :\

Comment: When in doubt, test. Pull up pgadmin and see what's actually in your database as you change the instance state and model configs. I'm not sure, but the stored value may vary between database types.

Comment: @ShaunOverton I think you misunderstood my question, I'm using MySQL in both cases. As described in my original post, on my python 2 branch, `None` is saved as empty string in DB, on the python 3 branch however, saving with None in the same field causes IntegrityError. I have a feeling the python 3 branch is behaving the right way, but it's also possible that the Django ORM silently converts null values to default values, in this case, empty string. I just want to understand what could cause this difference in behavior.